# React useState as a toggle triggers Re-render and re-initializes false on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, toggle

I have a simple question.
I am using a React toggle function based on useState toggle the rendering of a component.
It works, but on the Re-render of the parent component where the toggle function is defined it re-initializes that state as false and therefore hides the RegisterForm component once again.
What am I missing here?

```html
import RegisterForm from "./forms/Registerform";
import LoginForm from "./forms/LoginForm";
import { useState } from "react";
import useToggle from "./helpers/useToggle";
const LoginOrRegister = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useToggle(false)

    return(
    
        <>
        <div className="login">
        <p>Login to your user account</p>
        <LoginForm/>
        </div>
        <div className="register">
            <a href="" onClick={setToggle}>Not yet signed up? Register here</a>
            {toggle &&(<RegisterForm/>)}
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default LoginOrRegister;
```

and here is the useToggle custom hook.

```html
import { useState } from "react";
const useToggle = (initialState) => {
    const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(initialState);

    const toggler = () => { setToggleValue(!toggleValue) };
    return [toggleValue, toggler]
  };

  export default useToggle
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a custom useToggle hook on the parent component (which is re-rendered) and pass the data to the child component

```
const LoginOrRegister = ({toggle, setToggle}) => { ... }
```